# Why is my redux implementation resulting in a repetitive loop?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the component below, the getProducts function is called in useEffect once. Even when I comment out useEffect, it still goes into an interminable loop.

```
const Products = ({products, getProducts}) => {
    console.log("products", products)

    const [productCategory, setProductCategory] = useState({})
    const { category } = useParams();

  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('productsFilters', productsFilters)

      productsFilters.category = category;

      getProducts(productsFilters);   
    }, []);


   return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <ProductsBanner sectionBanner={productCategory.sectionBanner} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    products: state.products,  
  });

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts })(
    Products
  );
```

I get the following error. It seems to point to the mapStateToProps function as the culprit.

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14997)
```

This is the getProducts function that dispatches data to the redux store:

```
export const getProducts = (productsFilters) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("getProducts", getProducts);
  const queryParams = buildQueryParams(productsFilters);

  Axios.get(`${url}${queryParams}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("response.data", response.data);
      dispatch({
        type: ReducerType.SET_PRODUCTS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("error", error.response);
    });
};
```

This is the reducer:

```
export const ProductReducers = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ReducerType.SET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: In the line `productsFilters.category = category;` where does `productsFilters` come from?

Comment: @Marco import {productsFilters} from "./products.filters";

Comment: So do you see a lot of `console.log("products", products)` being printed before the error? Even if you comment the entire `useEffect`?

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer, I will have to test your question and get back to you in a minute.

Comment: The answer to your question is not entirely yes. getProducts in useEffect calls the backend and returns the data to the resolver. When useEffect is commented out, getProducts is not called, but the state of products in the resolver is returned in a continuous loop even though getProducts is not called. MapStateToProps seems to be the offending code..

Comment: @Marco A slight change to my last comment. it appears useEffect is never called. Statements in useEffect are not logged to the console. MapStateToProps just goes into an interminable loop.

Comment: Are there other parts of the application that change `state.products`? Because based on your explanation it seems like that `state.products` is being changed continuously from other parts. Can you comment out ALL the parts that interact with `state.products` and check if something change?

Comment: state.products is only changed in the reducer.

Comment: Ok but are there other parts that dispatch a `ReducerType.SET_PRODUCTS` action?

Comment: No, just the one I showed in getProducts.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create a codesandbox with the reproducible problem and share with us.

Comment: Marco, I explored your question some more about whether I was calling the getProducts function anywhere else. I thought I was logging entry into the function and this is what I mistakenly wrote: console.log("getProducts", getProducts);. That was the culprit.  It was calling getproducts recursively.

Comment: Ok @koque, all is well that ends well. I hope I was helpful.